# Sample Program of C using PPB_ImageData Google Native Client

Tags: c, google-nativeclient, getimagedata

Are there any reference sample examples in c language using the  PPB_ImageData in Google Native Client? I need to get the image data from the html canvas and process the image using a c-library.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the formal SDK has several C++ examples that leverage PPB_ImageData. You should be able write a C++ NaCl app that calls into a C-based library pretty easily.

If you're set on using the C API (I am the same way), then you will have to work from the SDK documentation and understand how PPB_ImageData works. However, I have a C-based Native Client app that uses PPB_ImageData. [The relevant source file is located here.](https://github.com/multimediamike/SaltyGME/blob/master/saltygme.c) Do a case-insensitive search for "imagedata" to find all the points of interest. Perhaps that will be useful to you.

Comment: Can you suggest an example which works the best. I am a newbie to Native Client.